# In an image, there are two nested rectangles, and they share two sides. How to use opencv to identify the two rectangles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Sorry, the original image cannot be uploaded due to some security reasons. The following is a schematic diagram:

original image：

[image: original image]

my goal：

[image: my goal]

Current situation：

[image: Current situation]

now I use `findContours` function to to complete the goal，The code currently used is（use Python 3 and `OpenCV`）:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 10, 150)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(ima, [contour], -1, (0, 0, 255), 5)
```

I also used the following function parameters：

```
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL，cv2.RETR_LIST，cv2.RETR_CCOMP，cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1，cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS
```

fact original image：[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounding-box of each white regions can be used to judge the simple rectangular "nested" relation.

Using `connectedComponentsWithStats`, AABB(axis-aligned bounding boxes) can be obtained.

(Following code is C++.)

```cpp
//Judge the rectangular nested relation
bool Is_A_Including_B( const cv::Rect &A, const cv::Rect &B, int Margin )
{
    int Left = A.x - Margin;
    int Right = Left + A.width + 2*Margin - 1;
    int Top = A.y - Margin;
    int Bottom = Top + A.height + 2*Margin - 1;
    
    auto B_br = B.br();
    return ( Left<=B.x  &&  B_br.x<=Right  &&  Top<=B.y  &&  B_br.y<=Bottom );
}

//main
int main()
{
    //Load Image and Binalize
    cv::Mat SrcImg = cv::imread( "Regs.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( SrcImg.empty() )return 0;

    cv::Mat BinImg;
    cv::threshold( SrcImg, BinImg, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );

    //Find Bounding Boxes of white regions
    std::vector< cv::Rect > BBs;
    {
        cv::Mat Labels, Stats, Centroids;
        int N = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats( BinImg, Labels, Stats, Centroids );

        BBs.reserve( N-1 );
        for( int i=1; i<N; ++i )
        {
            BBs.emplace_back(
                Stats.at<int>( i, cv::CC_STAT_LEFT ),
                Stats.at<int>( i, cv::CC_STAT_TOP ),
                Stats.at<int>( i, cv::CC_STAT_WIDTH ),
                Stats.at<int>( i, cv::CC_STAT_HEIGHT )
            );
        }
    }

    //Find nested region
    std::vector< cv::Rect > Found;
    for( auto i=BBs.begin(); i!=BBs.end(); ++i )
    {
        for( auto j=BBs.begin(); j!=BBs.end(); ++j )
        {
            if( i == j )continue;
            if( Is_A_Including_B( *i, *j, 5 ) )
            {   Found.push_back( *j );  }
        }
    }

    //Visualize
    cv::Mat ShowImg;
    cv::cvtColor( BinImg, ShowImg, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
    ShowImg *= 0.5;
    for( const auto &Rect : Found )
    {
        cv::rectangle( ShowImg, Rect, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 4 );
    }
    cv::imshow( "Result", ShowImg );
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I used python to reproduce your code and it performed well. But there are still problems for my actual task, maybe because there are other patterns and tables in the original image. You can check the following example pictures. At present, I suspect that the problem is not the nested rectangle but the presence of the table in the picture.
piclink：https://img1.imgtp.com/2023/09/11/2NpD4ckm.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I have no intention of trying to support more difficult image examples added later... However, for this example, I think followings :
(1)Pixel value (white and black) is reversed from the first example, so, threshold mode should be changed to THRESH_BINARY_INV.
(2)If you can actually ignore regions very near from image border, result of my code will be many cells of 2 grid tables.
(3)If so, I guess, you can join cells to 1 rectangle with some additional step (e.g. with morophorogy).

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem based on your suggestion. The rectangles and nested rectangles on the border were removed, leaving independent small rectangles. After forming the small rectangles into a large rectangle, I got the border I needed.